# set auto complete on sublime text 3 for custom html elements

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Good day,

how can I set auto complete on sublime text 3 for custom html elements, like for example if I type: `dog` then press tab it will become `<dog></dog>`.. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom [`.sublime-completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) file for this. Create a new file with JSON syntax in Sublime, using the following contents (of course customized to your needs):

```json
{
    "scope": "text.html - source, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "foo", "contents": "<foo>$0</foo>" },
        { "trigger": "bar", "contents": "<bar class=\"$1\">$0</bar>" },
        { "trigger": "baz", "contents": "<baz class=\"${1:myclass}\">$0</baz>" }
    ]
}
```

In the first example, typing `foo` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert `<foo>|</foo>` where `|` is the cursor position.

In the second example, typing `bar` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert `<bar class="|"></bar>`. The cursor will first be between the quotes following `class=` so you can enter your own class. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> again will place the cursor just before `</bar>`.

The third example works just like the second, except that the `class` now has a default value. This value will be highlighted after typing `baz` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> - you can either hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to keep the default value and move the cursor between the opening and closing tags, or you can enter your own value, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and move the cursor to between the opening and closing tags.

Once you have everything set up how you like, save the file as `Packages/User/HTML.sublime-completions`, where `Packages` is the folder opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`.

For more information, follow the link above. To learn more about placeholders and variables, check out [this documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html).

Good luck!