# Bracket autocomplete for jinja2 brackets in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have been using sublime text for almost 4 years now and have always struggled with jinja2 brackets that are in this format

```
{% if expression %}
```

Is there a way i can create a rule for autocomplete so that when i type `{%` it becomes `{%%}`

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188239/set-auto-complete-on-sublime-text-3-for-custom-html-elements) stackoverflow answer about sublime autocompletions

Comment: Thanks was looking for something similar :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help